# What do fire rate and reload speed mods do for Bows? (paris, despair)

Tags: warframe

I'd think reload speed would make it faster to recover from firing to be ready to pull the bow back, and fire rate would help with how long it takes to draw the bow. But, I haven't been able to notice any difference in either.

Do either (or both) of these have an effect and is it what I'd expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both mods have an effect on Paris (I have yet to acquire the other two) and they work exactly how you described them. Quotes from the [Paris wiki page](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Paris):

> - Reload speed mod increases the speed at which arrows are drawn from the quiver after each shot.
> - Fire rate mod increases the draw speed of the Paris, allowing you to charge an arrow much quicker.

Comment: Both mods have identical effects on all other bows.